# Is there any disadvantages of unique column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i'd like to ask a question regarding Unique columns in MySQL.
Would like to ask experts on which is a better way to approach this problem, advantages or disadvantages if there is any.

- Set a varchar column as unique
- Do a SQL INSERT IGNORE
- If affected rows > 0 proceed with running the code

versus

- Leave a varchar column as not-unique
- Do a search query to look for identical value
- If there is no rows returned in query, Do a SQL INSERT
- proceed with running the code

Comment: You are not going to INSERT anything in the second case?

Comment: I don't know the "behind the scenes" of mysql. But i think that the IGNORE keyword will run through your table, and then proceed to insert the value, if it was not found.

If you're using functions which can actually return the affected rows, i think the IGNORE function would be yourbest shot

Comment: If a value in a column has to be unique than use the tools the database gave you and build code to handle the exception that the database throws when you try to insert a value that is not unique.

Comment: If you run both code snippets twice, the first one will report that the row doesn't exist only once (since it will be inserted by the first run and exist the second time), while the second version will report the same non existent status every time and not change it.

Comment: @Thilo yeah, it will do insert on the second case

Answer (score 4):

Defining a column as an unique index has a few advantages, first of all when you define it as an "unique index" MySQL can optimize your index for unique values (same as a primary key) because mysql doesn't have to check if there are more rows with the same value so it can use an optimized algoritme for the lookups.

Also you are assured that there never will be a double entry in your database instead of handeling this in multiple places in your code.

When you don't define it as UNIQUE you first need to check if an records exists in your table, and then insert something wich requires 2 queries (and even a full table lock) instead of 1 wich decreases your performance and is more error prone

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

I'm leaving the fact that you would use the INSERT IGNORE wich IGNORES the exception when the entry allready exists in the database (Still you could use it for high performance operations maybe in some sort of special case). A normal INSERT will give you the feedback if an entry allready exists

Comment: Searching a table to ensure uniqueness doesn't work with concurrent inserts. Two inserts can both query the table and say OK to insert which gives non-unique entries.

Comment: That's why you need a full table lock in the process

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the 2 approaches is good.

You don't do `INSERT IGNORE` nor do you search. The searching part is also unreliable, because it fails at concurrency and compromises the integrity. Imagine this scenario:  you and I try to insert the same info into the database. We connect at the same time. Code in question determines that there's no such record in the database, for both of us. We both insert the same data. Now your column isn't unique, therefore we'll end up with 2 records that are the same - your integrity now fails.

What you do is set the column to `unique`, insert and catch the exception in the language of your choice. 
MySQL will fail in case of duplicate record, and any proper db driver for MySQL will interpret this as an exception.
Since you haven't mentioned what the language is, it's difficult to move forward with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a constraint like UNIQUE is better when it comes to query performance and data reliability. But there is also a trade-off when it comes to writing. So It's up to you which do you prefer. But in your case, since you also do INSERT IF NOT EXIST query, so I guess, it's better to just use the Constraint.